# Ill behaved smartphones or snobby users?

Tags: mobile

I'm receiving emails and I'm seeing messages on some websites that say something like 'Posted from my [smartphone]'.

I don't have a smartphone (yet), so I don't know if the message configuration is opt-in or whether it has an opt-out.

Do you have any experience with this type of message, can it easily be removed? Is the opt-out explicit?

Pd: 'Posted from my five year old laptop'

Comment: @Patrick, I think it's a usability issue as I wouldn't want to talk down to others from my 10.000USD price tagged smartphone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone who has never owned anything less than a smartphone, I can say this with certainty: every (major) smartphone operating system/mail application allows you to opt-out of the "Sent from my [device]" suffix that is the factory default. It's typically part of the mail signature, which is entirely configurable.

Comment: You might also note that a very large portion of users _never_ edit their settings either, and a slightly smaller group don't know that such settings can be changed. Even if people don't like it, the default behavior is sure to live on.

Answer (score 5):

As someone who communicates with smartphone owners, I find it helpful when I see "sent from iphone" as a signature. It helps explain the brevity of the message, that is, we will often write a shorter message via phone than what we do through a pc/mac keyboard.

Comment: That's an interesting point of view. I never thought of it like that. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it in the settings.  I think by default they add it, but it's pretty simple to remove, from the iPhone at least.  I'm sure you could with the others as well.